# Chrome Extension: How to get HTML element being hovered on by the mouse

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension that needs to get the ID of the element that is currently being hovered over by the mouse. Essentially, if the mouse is over a button, and I use a keyboard shortcut, it should be able to display an alert with the ID of the button.

Here's what I'm expecting to do:

**manifest.json**

```
    "commands": {
    "Display ID": {
        "suggested_key": {
            "default": "Ctrl+Shift+1",
            "mac": "Command+Shift+1"
        },
        "description": "Display ID"
    },
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {

    // Get the active tab when the command was fired
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true, currentWindow: true}, function(arrayOfTabs) {
        currentTabId = arrayOfTabs[0].id; 
    });

    // Display the ID of the HTML element where the mouse is currently hovering
    alert("This is the element's id:" + elementId); // How to do this part???

});
```

Please tell me if this is possible or not!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. I stored the element currently being hovered into a variable, and then recalled it when the keyboard shortcut command is executed. In essence I put a new mouseover event listener that tracked the current element being hovered on.

Comment: Hey! How did you manage to get the id of the hover element?